# adminhtml redirection pb from controller

Tags: adminhtml, controllers, redirect

In a module I created a new file type product option. The goal was to add a "file is valid" parameter.

With this option, I can define in the admin panel the option "is valid" state from the order detail view page and a button permits to submit the state change via a controller.

I would like after submission to be redirected to the order detail view page.

I tried `$this->_redirect('*/*');` but get 404 error

my option phtml
(app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/custoptiontypev6/options/customview/xfile.phtml)

```
    ...
    <span>
        <FORM id="xfile_state_sel" method="post" style="margin: 0px 5px 0px 15px;" action="<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("custoptiontypev6/xfile/update");?>">
            <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
            <input name="order_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_order_id ?>" />
            <input name="item_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_item_id ?>" />
            <input name="option_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_optionid ?>" />
            <input name="option_label" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_label ?>" />
            <INPUT type= "radio" name="<?php echo 'Xfile_option_'.$_optionid.'_'.$_label;?>" value="Checking" <?php echo $_checked_verif;?>> Being verified
            <INPUT type= "radio" name="<?php echo 'Xfile_option_'.$_optionid.'_'.$_label;?>" value="Files_OK" <?php echo $_checked_ok;?>> Files OK
            <INPUT type= "radio" name="<?php echo 'Xfile_option_'.$_optionid.'_'.$_label;?>" value="Files_not_OK" <?php echo $_checked_notok;?>> Files not OK
            <span><button type="submit" style="margin: 0px 5px 0px 15px;">Update state</button></span>
        </FORM>
</span>
```

The controller :

```
<?php
class Mine_Custoptiontypev6_XfileController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function updateAction()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        try {
            if (empty($post)) {
                //echo 'Invalid form data.';
            }

            /******* form processing *******/

    ...

        $this->_redirect('*/*');
    }  
}
?>
```

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When redirecting `*` means current, so with `$this->_redirect('*/*');` you are targeting the current module, current controller and index action.  As I see a closing `?>` in your controller (which by the way you should exclude, see [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.php-file-formatting.html)) I'm going to assume you have no more actions in that controller, including the index action, therefore the redirect fails in a 404 because the action does not actually exist.

You need to redirect to the adminhtml module, sales_order controller and view action instead so use the following:

```
$this->_redirect('adminhtml/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $someorderid));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
 $this->_redirect('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $orderId));
```

Where `$orderId` should be the order id to which you need to direct.